# How can I format date

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I get a date formatted like `2015-07-15 17:12:00 +0000`, but I want to display it like **Jul 15 2015**.

How can I do that?

Code:

```
func formatDate(date: String) -> String {

    if date != "" {
        var dateString = date
        dateString = dateString.substringToIndex(advance(minElement(indices(dateString)), 19))
       dateString = dateString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("", withString: " ")
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        var dateStr = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        var date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateStr!)
        return date
    }
    else {
        return ""
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input dateFormatter string is a bit off - it does not include the time zone and uses the wrong hour pattern. The following works and finally outputs

> Jul 15 2015

```
let dateStr = "2015-07-15 17:12:00 +0000"
var dateFormatterIn = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatterIn.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
let date = dateFormatterIn.dateFromString(dateStr)

let dateFormatterOut = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatterOut.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
print(dateFormatterOut.stringFromDate(date!))
```

For the correct date strings take a look at the [unicode docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial conversion from string to date failed. Try this:

```
func formatDate(dateString: String) -> String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"

    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
        formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        return formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    } else {
        return "Invalid dateString"
    }
}

println(formatDate("2015-07-15 17:12:00 +0000"))
```

Comment: @rimtej did you turn your date string back into an NSDate before using the formatter?

Answer (score 0):

NSDateformatter converts first the sql-like date string into NSDate and then back to a string with specific format

```
func formatDate(dateString: String) -> String {

  if !dateString.isEmpty {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
      return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }
  }
  return ""
}

formatDate("2015-07-15 17:12:00 +0000") // Jul 15 2015
```